# How to remove header of abstract chapter and do not apply for the rest chapters?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, footer

I try to make header and footer for a thesis. I wanna to remove header for abstract. However, when i use \pagestyle{plain}, all chapter headers are removed (not only abstract chapter).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%use oneside to ensure no blanks\
\usepackage[text={5.45in,8.5in}, left=1.5in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, headheight=15.91pt, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace, fancyhdr, amsmath, amssymb,amsthm, graphicx, color, lscape, longtable, booktabs, caption, wrapfig, hyperref, pdfpages, capt-of, lmodern, titlesec, tikz, lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\cfoot{\thepage}}

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr,ifthen}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nonumonpart}
%\usepackage{textcomp}


% Setup for headers and footers (fancyhdr)
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\rhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\nouppercase\rightmark}{}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancypagestyle{chapter}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}



\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancyplain}
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-5]


\part{First part} \label{part1}
\thispagestyle{chapter}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\thispagestyle{chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section II}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]


\chapter{Some chapter 2}
\thispagestyle{chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section II}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%use oneside to ensure no blanks\
\usepackage[text={5.45in,8.5in}, left=1.5in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, headheight=15.91pt, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace, fancyhdr, amsmath, amssymb,amsthm, graphicx, color, lscape, longtable, booktabs, caption, wrapfig, hyperref, pdfpages, capt-of, lmodern, titlesec, tikz, lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nonumonpart}

%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\cfoot{\thepage}}

% Setup for headers and footers (fancyhdr)
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\rhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\nouppercase\rightmark}{}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{chapter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    \lipsum[1-5]
        
    \part{First part} \label{part1}
    \thispagestyle{chapter}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \thispagestyle{chapter}
    
    \section{Section I}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Section II}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Subsection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Subsection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \chapter{Some chapter 2}
    \thispagestyle{chapter}
    
    \section{Section I}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Section II}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Subsection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Subsection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
\end{document}
```

If you observe, the abstract is not a chapter! So you can use `chapter*` to solve it. If you take another look at this solution, you will see that the second page is still with a header (a blank header). However, you should not be worried about it, because no abstract will be too large, so it will need two pages!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the `\thispagestyle{chapter}` stuff (and don't define the `chapter` pagestyle. The default `plain` pagestyle will do the same.

Don't use pagestyle `fancyplain`. It is obsolete and may give unexpected results.

For the Abstract, just give a `\pagestyle{plain}` before it, and a `\pagestyle{fancy}` after the `\part`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%use oneside to ensure no blanks\
\usepackage[text={5.45in,8.5in}, left=1.5in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, headheight=15.91pt, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace, fancyhdr, amsmath, amssymb,amsthm, graphicx, color, lscape, longtable, booktabs, caption, wrapfig, hyperref, pdfpages, capt-of, lmodern, titlesec, tikz, lipsum}

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr,ifthen}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nonumonpart}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

% Setup for headers and footers (fancyhdr)
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\rhead{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\nouppercase\rightmark}{}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-5]

\part{First part} \label{part1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Some chapter}


\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section II}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Some chapter 2}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section II}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```